# intersection observer multiple animation

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve different animation for many elements on scroll, so instead of using window.scroll i'm using intersection observer api, but i want to know if my approach is effective and won't cause performance drop, basically what i did is make a single function to hold the entire animation of the website and check if the target has specific class then do something like so :

```
const one = document.querySelector('.one')
const two = document.querySelector('.two')
const three = document.querySelector('.three')

function animation (entires) {
    entires.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.isIntersecting) {
            if(entry.target.classList.contains('text')) {
               entry.target.style.transform = 'translateY(0)'
            }
            if(entry.target.classList.contains('one')) {
               entry.target.style.transform = 'translateX(100px)'
            }
            if(entry.target.classList.contains('two')) {
               entry.target.style.transform = 'translateY(0)'
            }
            if(entry.target.classList.contains('three')) {
               entry.target.style.transform = 'skew(10deg)'
            }
        }
    })
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(animation)
```

i'm not experienced enough but i feel like it's spaghetti code and not efficient and how can i observe multiple elements ? do i have to repeat observer.observe for each element i want to observe ?